# Order result by IDs with the most recent date

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I tried a lot, but I cannot figure out a way to do this:

I have a table with (not unique) IDs and dates. All entries should be selected in the end, but they need to be sorted.

Table:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    date    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2017-12-10 |
|  1 | 2015-05-22 |
|  7 | 2016-04-05 |
|  2 | 2017-12-12 |
|  2 | 2014-03-10 |
|  7 | 2016-01-14 |
|  1 | 2016-08-17 |
+----+------------+
```

What I need:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    date    |
+----+------------+
|  2 | 2017-12-12 |
|  2 | 2014-03-10 |
|  1 | 2017-12-10 |
|  1 | 2016-08-17 |
|  1 | 2015-05-22 |
|  7 | 2016-04-05 |
|  7 | 2016-01-14 |
+----+------------+
```

I need everything "grouped" by the ids, starting with the id that has the most recent date linked to it.

```
id: 2 / date: 2017-12-12
```

has the most recent date, so now all rows with Id 2 follow, ordered by the date descending. After that, which "block" of ids comes next is determined again by the next most recent date and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a subquery that groups by id, we get the max date, then joining this to the source data gives us the max date on every row to sort by.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94a8c71/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `date`)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-12-10 00:00:00'),
    (1, '2015-05-22 00:00:00'),
    (7, '2016-04-05 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2017-12-12 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2014-03-10 00:00:00'),
    (7, '2016-01-14 00:00:00'),
    (1, '2016-08-17 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
inner join (
  select id, max(`date`) maxdate
  from table1
  group by id
  ) g on t.id = g.id
order by g.maxdate DESC, t.id, t.date DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94a8c71/4/0)**:

```
| id |                 date |
|----|----------------------|
|  2 | 2017-12-12T00:00:00Z |
|  2 | 2014-03-10T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2017-12-10T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2016-08-17T00:00:00Z |
|  1 | 2015-05-22T00:00:00Z |
|  7 | 2016-04-05T00:00:00Z |
|  7 | 2016-01-14T00:00:00Z |
```

Comment: I implemented it and it works like a charm! I figured I had to use some subqueries and grouping but couldn't quite get there on my own. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

if your table is `stack`

```
SELECT * FROM `stack` LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT  * FROM `stack` GROUP BY `id` )t1 ON
`stack`.`id` = t1.`id` ORDER BY t1.`date` DESC,`stack`.`date` DESC
```